# Visual Studio 2008: How to customize the font size increment applied by IncreaseTextEditorFontSize?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, font-size

In **Visual Studio 2008**, the font size of the editor can be increased or decreased by using the commands `Macros.Samples.Accessibility.IncreaseTextEditorFontSize` and `Macros.Samples.Accessibility.DecreaseTextEditorFontSize`. I can associate keyboard shortcuts to both these commands. For example, `Ctrl+<` to decrease and `Ctrl+>` to increase.

Now, if I press `Ctrl+>` once then the font size of text in the editor is increased by a certain amount. How can I customize how much the font size is increased or decreased by these commands? That is how do I control the font size increment/decrement applied by this command?

Note: This is a question specific to Visual Studio 2008 and older versions. This does not apply to Visual Studio 2010 and newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View + Other Windows + Macro Explorer.  Expand Samples and Accessibility.  Right-click the IncreaseTextEditorFontSize macro and select Edit.  Modify the value of *fontSizeIncrement*.